# Maven modules - produce artifact with a mixture of sources from multiple modules

Tags: maven

We have a multi module maven project with the following layout

project
   - common (contains DTOs and other utils)
   - business (containes business services)
   - presentation (presentation related)

Now, we have a webservice exposed from business module and we have to give a jar file with just service interface (from 'business' module) and DTOs (from 'common' module) to a dependent application which wants to consume the web service.

What is the best way to produce this artifact using maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most elegant way I could find to solve the problem (without breaking Maven recommendation of one project, one artifact principle) is as below.

Create a maven module named web-services and use CXF-Maven plugin to generate the classes required for consuming the webservice. The artifact produced (jar) will have the required classes to be distributed to web service clients.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Removing the child module for webservice from parent project's POM xml should help (if i understood the question correctly).

Comment: Not sure what you meant, all these are separate modules and we need the artifacts to be produced in that way for normal application development and deployment. For a web service client, we just need to supply the interface and dependent DTOs to the third party.